# Android: Activity- Image Visibility gone when changing the activity

Tags: android, android-activity

Hi i have a activity with a list view when i click the list , it goes to login activity when the login is success a icon appears on the header,(header is common for all activites), so far itz working the problem is after the icon appear when i change the activity and come back to same activity i couldnot see the icon , below is my code

```
img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.red);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        Bundle b = i.getExtras();
        if (b != null) {
            boolean redonly = b.getBoolean("redonly");
            if (redOnly) {
                img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Constants.isredonly=true;
            } else {
                img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Constants.isredonly=false;
            }
        } else {
            img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

below is my login activity

```
public void onClick(View v) {

                String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
                 Intent myIntent = new Intent(loginActivity.this, myActivity.class);
                 myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                if (password.equals("1234")) {
                     myIntent.putExtra("redonly", true);
                } else {
                     myIntent.putExtra("redonly", false);
                }
                startActivity(myIntent);
                finish();
            }
```

Any suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: `boolean red = b.getBoolean("red");` Is that a typo? Elsewhere you talk about `redOnly` or `redonly`.

Comment: yeah its a typo..my bad..i edited, thankyou

Comment: Actually, that's still wrong. Can you paste the real source, please? And can you put in a `Log.d(TAG, "redOnly="+redOnly);` after you read the value from the intent, and let us know what it says?